# Computing problem in probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is a simple problem but I cannot solve it just because I don't know some theorems and definitions.Could you hint or explain how to solve?

Let X and U be 2 independent probability variable.X is normal distribution with expected value 0 and variance 1 and $P(U=1)=P(U=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and define $Y=UX$

1.find P(X+Y=0)

2.find probability distribution of Y

3.find E[XY]

4.show that X,Y dependent

My idea:1. since U has probability of 1/2 to be -1 therefore P(X+Y=0)=P(U=-1)=1/2 ??

2.P_Y(A)=P(Y\in A) then have no idea how to continue

3.-4. if $E[XY]\not=0$ then $E[XY]\not= E[X]E[Y]=0$ so X,Y dependent.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

1. $\{X+Y = 0\} = \{X+UX = 0\} = \{X(1+U) = 0\}$. This event occurs either when $X = 0$ (zero probability) or $U = -1$ (probability 1/2).
2. $\{UX \leq y\} = \{U = 1, X \leq y\} \cup \{U = -1, X \geq -y\}$. These two sets are disjoint; therefore, $P\{Y\leq y\} = \frac{1}{2}P\{X\leq y\} + \frac{1}{2}P\{X\geq -y\}$. As $X$ is a standard normal, $P\{X\leq y\} = P\{X\geq -y\}$ and so $P\{Y\leq y\} = P\{X\leq y\}$. Thus, $Y$ also has the standard normal distribution.
3. $E[XY] = E[UX^2] = E[U]E[X^2] = 0$ since $E[U] = 0$.
4. Let $A = (-1,1)$ and $B = (1,2)$. Then, $P(Y\in B|X\in A) = 0 \neq P(Y \in B)$.